# Is sending ArrayBuffers through socket.io significantly faster than JSON?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, socket.io-1.0

My internet is extremely slow and lately I've been messing around making multiplayer games with socket.io. Usually I just send JSON objects with 5 or six properties to a node.js server running socket.io. 
But just recently I read that you could send ArrayBuffers as well. So my question is, would encoding things like a players change in position into 5 or six bytes (assuming I could in the game) make a big difference in latency?

Comment: have you tested to find out?

Comment: If you're talking about a 6 byte Array Buffer versus 30 bytes of JSON, it is unlikely you can even measure the difference in performance between those two on a single transaction.   Also, remember that latency is related to the rountrip time of a packet which at these small sizes has more to do with the network infrastructure and endpoint responsiveness than the size of the packet.

Comment: Aah thanks @jfriend00 what would you say the cutoff point for packet size is where size starts to actually matter

Comment: You'd have to set up a test bed to really figure it out.  It would depend upon your actual end-to-end bit transfer rate and how much of a difference was relevant to you and how much other things in the roundtrip dwarfed the actual data transfer time.  A moderate speed internet connection of 10Mbps can transfer 1300 bytes/millisecond once it gets going.  Your latency is likely held back more by other things in the network infrastructure besides packet size.